# Keyup fires on backspace but preview color does not change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am implementing a preview color. When I input a color in the input text box, the preview div will change color. For instance, when the input is #000, the preview div changes to black. But when I start pressing backspace, the preview div does not change color. I put an alert to check the input text box value and it does change to '00' when I start pressing backspace. What am I missing here?

Here is a fiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/8atcbfwh/1/

```js
<!-- Jquery code -->
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').on('keyup', function(event) {
    $('#preview').css('background-color', '#' + $('#test').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Html code -->
<input id="test"></input>
<div id="preview" style="width: 50px;height:50px;border: 1px solid black"></div>
```

Comment: You could check the length of `$('#test').val()` and if it's less than 3, just set it back to a default color.

Comment: But a value of #00 should make the background-color invalid, isn't it or ?

Comment: jQuery `.css()` doesn't attach invalid values I guess.

Comment: @coffeeak so #00 invalid and what is the color you expect?

Comment: @Teemu Thank you, your comment guided me to the right direction. Found my answer on another thread. Posted an answer in case it might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

After @Teemu pointed out the .css probably doesn't attach invalid values, I did another search on stackoverflow and found this: [change background color of div with jquery that has an !important tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674158/change-background-color-of-div-with-jquery-that-has-an-important-tag)

Before assigning a color to the preview div, I now clear the background-color and THEN give it the value of the input textbox.

New working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/8atcbfwh/3/

```js
$('#test').on('keyup', function(event) {
    $('#preview').css('background-color', '');
    $('#preview').css('background-color', '#' + $('#test').val());
    $("#color").html('#' + $('#test').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test"/>
<div id="preview" style="width: 50px;height:50px;border: 1px solid black;"></div>
<div id="color">
</div>
```

Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

This help you :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Html code -->
        <input id="test">
        <div id="preview" style="width: 50px;height:50px;border: 1px solid black"></div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('#test').on('keyup', function(event) {
                if(event.keyCode == 8)
                    $('#preview').css('background-color', '');
                $('#preview').css('background-color', '#' + $('#test').val());
            });
           
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```