# Axios: How to add CSS styling to an input upon success

Tags: jquery, axios

I have been using AJAX for years, where you can add any JQuery you want after the success function. Is there a way doing this with Axios?

I have tried putting into a then function without success:

```
 .then(function () {
  $("#rate").css("background-color","green");                
 })
```

Comment: After the typo fix it works?

Comment: The HTTP works, but not the CSS.  I double checked.

Comment: maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674158/change-background-color-of-div-with-jquery-that-has-an-important-tag