# Can I use jquery to remove/negate css !important rule?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If there is a CSS rule that uses `!important`, is there a way to remove the `!important` rule so that I can make further downstream style changes with JS or jQuery?

**theirs.css**

```
div.stubborn { display: none !important; }
```

**mine.js**

```
$('.stubborn').fadeIn();  // won't work because of !important flag
```

Unfortunately, I do not have control over the style applying the `!important` rule so I need a work-around.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot override `!important` without using `!important` as inline/internal style below the included `theirs.css`.

You can define a `!important` style and add it to `.stubborn` then adjust the opacity.. See below,

**CSS:**

```
div.hidden_block_el { 
   display: block !important;
   opacity: 0;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.stubborn')
    .addClass('hidden_block_el')
    .animate({opacity: 1});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/jjWJT/1/

Alternate approach (inline),

```
$('.stubborn')
    .attr('style', 'display: block !important; opacity: 0;')
    .animate({opacity: 1});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/jjWJT/

Comment: +1 Sadly this is a the type of hack one needs to employ when there is a explosion at the "!important" factory

Comment: some good reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: +1 I second _inline_ approach, especially in my case using jQuery Mobile.

Comment: + 1 for inline approach, really.

Answer (score 5):

Just add a `style=""` tag to any images with this issue, hopefully they all have some sort of defining class to them that it's easy to do so.

```
$('div.stubborn').attr('style', 'display: inline !important;');​
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UCAcr/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new class to apply fade.

CSS:

```
div.stubborn { display: none !important; }
div.stubborn.fade-ready { display: block !important; opacity: 0; }
```

JS:

```
$('.stubborn').addClass('fade-ready').animate({opacity: 1}); //to show
$('.stubborn').fadeOut(function() {$(this).removeClass('fade-ready');}); //to hide
```

**DEMO [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/kuQej/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

you can add a new css style with the !important added to it that will override the original style

This is from another answer in javascript:

```
function addNewStyle(newStyle) {
var styleElement = document.getElementById('styles_js');
if (!styleElement) {
    styleElement = document.createElement('style');
    styleElement.type = 'text/css';
    styleElement.id = 'styles_js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styleElement);
}
styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newStyle));
}

 addNewStyle('td.EvenRow a {display:inline !important;}')
```

this answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462537/overriding-important-style-using-javascript)

Also I believe that you can add styling like this

```
        .css({ 'display' : 'block !important' });
```

in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I have tried several methods, but the best results I've obtained by adding the CSS style (!important) in a separate class, then remove with jQuery:

CSS:

```
.important-css-here { display: block !important;}
```

In jQuery:

```
$("#selector").addClass("important-css-here");
```

then, when I need:

```
$("#selector").removeClass("important-css-here");
```

work like a charm ;-)