# Remove (!important) attribute from class

Tags: jquery, css, attributes

I need to remove a `!important`-attribute from an element using jQuery. Is that possible?

While I wanted to create a js-fiddle for it, I noticed it doesn't even work with a not-`!important` style:

http://jsfiddle.net/u4q2P/2/

What's wrong with my code?

So if someone could explain why jQuery doesn't remove the CSS-property like how it's supposed to be (see f.e. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2442-Clearing-Inline-CSS-Properties-With-jQuery.htm)

Comment: that does not answer my question why it doesn't even remove non-important attributes - but thanks for the downvotes to those that didn't even read the question

Comment: It does answer your first question, your second is irrelevant to the first and your title.

Comment: why using jquery when you can use the backspace button?

Comment: what using backspace? Do you really think I'm not clever enough to just delete the important-rule if that would be a viable solution? Such an answer is even getting upvotes??

Comment: I'm tryng to say that if you want to set a property, just set it via jquery with !important, you don't need to remove the !important from the existing property.

Comment: I have set the actual property in my actual code on a specific element to margin: 0px !important which overrides the class on that element which has margin: 20px and I need to reset it to margin: 20px via jQuery (just believe me) and I can't remove the overwrite via jQuery

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and set `!important` inside your style value to override it:

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function () {
    $('#myDiv').attr('style', 'padding: 0px !important;');
})
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4q2P/3/)**

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want the padding to be default again?

If you want the default value of padding back: http://jsfiddle.net/u4q2P/4/

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function () {
    $('#myDiv').css('padding', 'inherit');
})
```

Edit, since the question is not very clear I made this edit

If you want to set the padding to 0 you use: http://jsfiddle.net/u4q2P/5/

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function () {
    $('#myDiv').css('padding','0px');
})
```

And if you had made a good jsfiddle we could help you in seconds: http://jsfiddle.net/u4q2P/6/

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function () {
    $('#myDiv').attr('style', 'padding: 0px !important');
})
```

Comment: no, I want to remove the padding-attribute!

Comment: That is equal to not setting the padding and that is equal to inherit....

Comment: @Bondye This does not work if padding has attribute `!important`

Comment: @user1479606 Than the OP has made a confusing jsfiddle..

Answer (score 1):

Orignally taken from [Can I use jquery to remove/negate css !important rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890739/can-i-use-jquery-to-remove-negate-css-important-rule)
Unfortunately, you cannot override !important without using !important as inline/internal style below the included theirs.css.

You can define a !important style and add it to .stubborn then adjust the opacity.. See below,

**CSS:**

```
div.hidden_block_el { 
   display: block !important;
   opacity: 0;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.stubborn')
.addClass('hidden_block_el')
.animate({opacity: 1});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/jjWJT/1/

Alternate approach (inline),

```
$('.stubborn')
.attr('style', 'display: block !important; opacity: 0;')
.animate({opacity: 1});
```

Answer (score 0):

An empty style is nothing. Put in a 0 or something at the padding :)

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function () {
    $('#myDiv').css('padding', '0');
})
```

Comment: jQuery is supposed to REMOVE attributes if you give them an empty value!

Comment: And how's that working out for you? I changed my fiddle to a 0 and it worked!