# Overriding !important with css or jquery

Tags: jquery, css, content-script

(This is using content scripts in a chrome extension)

I need to overwrite some css properties that the webpage has labeled as `!important`. Is this possible?

For instance, if I want to get rid of the border that is labeled important:

```
$(".someclass").css('border','none'); //does not work
```

Comment: Did you search SO? I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462537/overriding-important-style-using-javascript

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: That question is about Javascript; this question is about jQuery. The solution may be the same in the end, but the question's author wouldn't've known that (nor did I), and I think most devs would agree it's best practice to use a jQuery solution, when one exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply !important using .css()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$( '.someclass' ).each(function () {
    this.style.setProperty( 'border', 'none', 'important' );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Gtr54/

The `.setProperty` method of an element's `style` object enables you to pass a third argument which represents the priority. So, you're overriding an !important value with your own !important value. As far as I know, it is not possible to set the !important priority with jQuery, so your only option is the built-in `.setProperty` method.

Comment: Fails in IE8 with "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: @StuartDobson Yes, fails in IE8 -.-

Comment: Fails in Mosaic 2, too. :-P

Comment: It's a great answer with one caveat - if  `$('#container).style` does not work - use `$('#container)[0].style` instead

Comment: @yaru Yes, the `style` property is only available on the DOM element itself, not on the jQuery object.

Comment: bless you sir, bless you

Answer (score 51):

You can also do this:

```
$(".someclass").css("cssText", "border: none !important;");
```

Comment: this will overwrite the style

Answer (score 15):

This should help.

```
$(".someclass").attr("style","border:none!important");
```

Updated, so as not to overwrite all styles:

```
var existingStyles = $(".someclass").attr("style");
$(".someclass").attr("style", existingStyles+"border:none!important");
```

Comment: Will replace all other styles

Answer (score 1):

we can just add class using jquery

```
$("someclass").addClass("test");

<style>
.test{
border:none !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This won't work with a dynamically generated style (such as height or color). It's just ridiculous that [jQuery devs are pitching this as a viable workaround.](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11173) 

Answer (score 0):

there is also another way

```
$("#m_divList tbody").find("tr[data-uid=" + row.uid + "]").find('td').css("cssText", "color: red !important;");
```

**css("cssText", "color: red !important;");**

Answer (score -1):

Use this below code to override the important in jQuery.

```
<style>  
  div.woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-disabled {
    display: none ! important;
  }
</style>

<div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-disabled">
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('.woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart').attr('style', 'display: block !important;');
    });
  </script>
</div>
```