# Why cannot I change the background property in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

the html:

```
<div class="tpc_content">
    ....
</div>
```

Here's the style snippet:

```
<style>
.tpc_content{ background: url('/aliwayWaterMaker.php') repeat !important; }
</style>
```

When I invoked `$('.tpc_content').css('background');` at console from developer tools in Chrome, the output is:

```
"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(http://www.aliway.com/aliwayWaterMaker.php) repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box"
```

Then I tried to set this css property via command: `$('.tpc_content').css('background', "rgba(20, 30, 40, 0)");`, after which I sent `$('.tpc_content').css('background');` again, and the output was still:

```
"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(http://www.aliway.com/aliwayWaterMaker.php) repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box"
```

Could anyone tell me how to remove the background image via jquery or javascript after the page loading?

Comment: @DutGRIFF That's depends on what the php returns, maybe it returns an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cssText` to override the `!important` with another one:

```
$('.tpc_content').css('cssText', 'background: rgba(20, 30, 40, 0.5) !important');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/88L66/

Source: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2066

Comment: This one works for me, Thanks! By the way, Could you explain why doesn't @Seth McClaine's answer works?

Comment: I believe it's because the syntax is wrong. It should be: `$('.tpc_content').attr('style', 'background: rgba(20, 30, 40, 0) !important;');`

Answer (score 3):

Its because you have !important in your css....

over ride with 
`$('.tpc_content').attr('style', 'backround="url(http://www.aliway.com/aliwayWaterMaker.php) repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box !important"');`

But its better to just not use !important in your css

Comment: Could you give me an explanation about why `!important` restrains my change to the property?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css

Comment: because your css is always there, even if you modify the dom. the !important will over ride anything you change in the dom unless you put !important in the dom

Comment: I didn't make it work bro.. I tried this one:  `$('.tpc_content').attr('style', 'backround="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important"');`, and the background didn't remove.

Comment: @Judking why are you using `!important` to begin with?  Why don't you just move the class to the very bottom of your CSS or after any CSS stylizing?

Comment: This is not my page, bro. I have to do something to remove this background image after the page load complete. @RayanBouajram

Comment: you have to include all of the original styles with this method (so background = "url(....)

Answer (score 0):

Judking- "Could you give me an explanation about why !important restrains my change to the property?"

css falls in the following order

class can be over written by id

```
call < id
```

id can be over written by inline style

```
id < inline
```

unless you use !important then what ever has !important takes precedence... the only way to overwrite that is to add !important to a superseding identifier

What you have is a class that has !important and are trying to over ride

```
.class + !important > inline
```

the only way to over ride this is to make your inline !important

```
.class + !important < inline + !important
```

Comment: Clear enough, thanks! but I'm confused why didn't your `$('.tpc_content').attr('style', 'backround="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important"');` work for me.

Comment: because you have to re-define everything this is printed when you do $('.tpc_content').attr('style'); it doesnt just add it clears out everything

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with raw DOM elements, though if you're using jQuery you probably get those from jQuery.get():

[Overriding !important with css or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962962/overwriting-important-with-css-or-jquery)

!important restricts what you can do with a .css() call since anything marked as !important by the author has a higher specificity than the styles you're applying using elem.css().