# Adding '!important' property to css inside iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a frame and dynamically applying the 'header' class to the frame.
It is working fine but need to add '!important' at the end of each css property.

I applied in the following way but not working.

```
var divblock = '.header';
$('#frame').contents().find('header').addClass('header');

$('#frame').contents().find(divblock).css({
    'color': objProp.css[pageSection]['color']+ '!important',
    'background-color': objProp.css[pageSection]['background']+'!important',
    'font-size': objProp.css[pageSection]['font-size']+'!important'
});
```

Comment: Adding **!important** is not possible with `jQuery .css`, you have to use it like `setAttribute("style", "width: 12px !important");`

Plain JS

Comment: @abhi Nope. It can be done with jquery. `.css(property,value,priority)`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy It never worked for me, so I used the `setAttribute` method only.

Comment: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962962/overriding-important-with-css-or-jquery) answer may help

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy there is no overload with those parameters in css-function: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

We can't add the !important using jQuery but you can override the style like as follow.

```
// CSS styles 
.header{
  color:red;
 }

.importantHeader{
   color: black !important;
}

//script

$('#frame').contents().find('header').addClass('imporatantHeader');
```

Not this but you can use same class number of times and for this you have to just write one line of code **jQuery Code**.

This called reusable.

Good Luck ['}