# How to override css media query !important property using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to override css media query !important property using jquery. matchMedia not working issue

```
#div{
  padding-left:10px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  #div{
    padding-left:15px !important;
  }
}

var minql = window.matchMedia("(max-width:475px) and (min-width:320px)");
if (minql.matches) {
  $("#div").css({"padding-left": "30px" });
}
```

Comment: please have a look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962962/overriding-important-with-css-or-jquery

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462537/overriding-important-style/1577204#1577204

Comment: In fact, using `!important` is completely unnecessary in the code you have shared. Do not use it unless absolutely necessary—it defeats the purpose of cascading styles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
  /* the viewport is at least 400 pixels wide */
} else {
/* the viewport is less than 400 pixels wide */
}
```

You can also refer to this example: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291873/window-width-not-the-same-as-media-query)