# How to the change color of links to specific file extensions with a userscript?

Tags: greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

My school website has homework download links and I want to distinguish them by coloring them different colors.
EG: Microsoft Word files would be blue and .RTF files would be green.
Since I'm new to this none of my scripts are working.

My script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Homework Help
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Color links for different file extensions
// @author       You
// @match        (My School Website)
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

function getFileExtension(filename) {
    return filename.split('.').pop();
}

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...
    var links = document.getElementByTagName("a");
    var element;

    for (var i = 0; i < links.lenth(); i++){

        element = rtfs[i];

        if( getFileExtension(element.href) == "rtf" ){
            element.style.color = "green";
        }
    }
})();
```

I tried googling it but found no solution.

Comment: Typo: `getElementByTagName` should be `getElementsByTagName`. You can detect such simple bugs by using the built-in devtools debugger: add `debugger;` line somewhere inside the code, for example after `'use strict';`, open devtools (F12), reload the page, the debugger will pop up, so you can step through the code and inspect the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your school's website may well load the file list using AJAX.  If
   that is the case, you need to use AJAX-aware techniques.
2. Also, as pointed out by wOxxOm, there is a syntax error in the code.
3. Occasionally, depending on the site's CSS you may need to [use the `!important` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962962/overriding-important-with-css-or-jquery).

The following complete script uses jQuery and `waitForKeyElements()` to address items 1 & 2 (it works on static pages too):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Color code links by file extension
// @match    http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directive is needed to restore the proper sandbox.

// PICK A MORE PRECISE SELECTOR IF YOU CAN.
waitForKeyElements ("a", colorLink);

function colorLink (jNode) {
    var fileHref        = jNode.attr ("href");
    if ( ! fileHref)    return; //-- Not every link has an href.

    var fileExt         = fileHref.split ('.').pop ().toLowerCase ();
    switch (fileExt) {
        case "rtf":
            jNode.css ("color", "green");
        break;
        case "doc":
            jNode.css ("color", "pink");
        break;
        default:
            //-- No action needed.
        break;
    }
}
```

---

Note: The jQuery selector `"a"` will filter through every link!  But we need page details to pick a more targeted selector.  Use the techniques shown at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048223/choosing-and-activating-the-right-controls-on-an-ajax-driven-site), to narrow the selection.