# jQuery: Adding important to an inline style function

Tags: jquery

I need to add "!important" to a function that adds an inline style however I have a funny feeling that the way the script is done, it won't work, I am hoping someone might shine a light on the issue.

In my jQuery example if I remove

```
 + ' !important'
```

The script works fine however I need to add the important part to override other CSS I don't have access to edit.

The end output will look like:

```
  <a href="" class="eaContIcon" style="background:#0033ff !important;">
    Text
    <span class="customHex">#0033ff</span>
  </a>
```

HTML

```
<div class="mobContCon">

  <a href="" class="eaContIcon">
    Text
    <span class="customHex"></span>
  </a>

  <a href="" class="eaContIcon">
    Text
    <span class="customHex">#0033ff</span>
  </a>

  <a href="" class="eaContIcon">
    Text
    <span class="customHex">#ff00ff</span>
  </a>

</div>
```

CSS

```
a.eaContIcon {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ff0000 !important;
  margin: 0 1px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.customHex {
  display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.mobContCon a').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('eaContIcon');
  });

  $('.eaContIcon').css('background', function() {
    return $(this).children('.customHex').text() + ' !important';

  });

});
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/j81whpxa/49/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962962/overriding-important-with-css-or-jquery has a few different strategies for this. 
Here's one working: https://jsfiddle.net/fhv1kztm/

Comment: Thanks @JeremyNinnes that worked great!

Answer (score 1):

This was sorted by a comment on the original post by Jeremy

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.mobContCon a').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('eaContIcon');
  });

  $('.eaContIcon').attr('style', function() {
    return 'background:' + $(this).children('.customHex').text() + ' !important';

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be to transfer !important into your .customHex class and remove it in your jQuery code. It should look like this:

```
.customHex {
display: none !important;
}
```

For references you can refer to this link:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you understand what the code is doing, I need the output of the inline style to include !important

Answer (score 0):

**I have remove extra js code that might not needed. You can try this, it will work.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mobContCon a').each(function() {
      let objthis = $(this);
      let backgroundColor = objthis.children('.customHex').text() + ' !important';

      objthis.addClass('eaContIcon');
      objthis.attr("style","background :" + backgroundColor);

     });
});
```

Comment: Another great example, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Checking **Hex color** code is `empty or not` with help of **conditional (ternary) operator** and `override background color`.
I hope below snippet will help you a lot.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mobContCon a').each(function () {
        var _this = $(this);
        _this.addClass('eaContIcon');
    
        var getColorCode = _this.find('.customHex').text();
        getColorCode != ''?  _this.attr("style", "background:" + getColorCode + '!important'): ''
    });
});
```

```css
a.eaContIcon {
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ff0000 !important;
    margin: 0 1px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.customHex {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mobContCon">
    <a href="" class="eaContIcon">
        Text
        <span class="customHex"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="eaContIcon">
        Text
        <span class="customHex">#0033ff</span>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="eaContIcon">
        Text
        <span class="customHex">#ff00ff</span>
    </a>
</div>
```