# Unable to edit CSS style using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML element that looks like this:

```
<p style=​"font:​12px verdana !important;​margin:20px !important;​">​…​</p>​
```

Now at some point I need to edit the margin attribute through Javascript. The code looks something like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[3].getElementsByTagName('p')[0].style.margin='0'
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[3].getElementsByTagName('p')[0].style.marginLeft = '150px'
```

However, this isn't working. After I check the value of 'margin' and 'marginLeft' before and after the code, the values remain the same. If I use Google developer tools and manually change the Javascript then the issue is resolved. Can anyone tell me why the code above is not changing the value of the style? I also tried using `setAttribute` but that did not work either.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462537/overriding-important-style

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName('div')[3].getElementsByTagName('p')[0].setAttribute("style", "margin : 0 !important");

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with jquery:

```
$('selector').css('cssText','font:​12px verdana !important;​margin-left:150px !important;');
```

making of this way, it overrides your inline style, so be careful if you modify your style dinamically

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery for this its very easy:

```html
$( ".selector" ).css( "background-color","#fff" );
```

OR you can access your element in this way

```
var elements = $( "body" ).find("div");
var p = elements[3].find("p");
$p[0].css("margin","0px");
$p[0].css("margin-left","150px");
```

if you don't want to use jQuery then you first check that you are accessing/selecting the right div and p tag you can alert the length of elements found and check is 3rd element have the one which you want to update?

Comment: This won't work when `!important` is specified inline.

Comment: I don't see a jQuery tag on the question.