# How can use JavaScript to set a style with !important?

Tags: javascript, css

I have no problems except when trying to add `!important`. It just will not take. I need to add it in order to override a font size dynamically.

Here is how I am adjusting the style:

```
function newFont(newSizeA) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
    for(i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].style.fontSize = newSizeA + 'px!important';
    }

}

newFont(20);
```

With `!important` it fails, without `!important` it works.

EDIT: This needs to work back to IE8 so I am hoping there is a cross browser solution that someone knows of.

Comment: `newSizeA + 'px !important';`

Comment: It doesn't work, see here:   http://jsfiddle.net/ovrbhz8L/

Comment: Specifying `!important` with or without a space before for dynamic styles don't seem to work. See: http://jsfiddle.net/ey8x3emy/

Comment: thanks for the link, using this meathod seeems to work:   elems[i].style.cssText = 'font-size:' + newSizeB + 'px !important';

Comment: check out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462537/overriding-important-style ?

Answer (score 9):

Your CSS [won't parse](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#parse-a-css-value) the `!important` declaration when written that way (it's expecting only legal values for `fontSize` in the value space, which means numbers, not numbers and a string). Instead, you can write it this way, by setting the `style` attribute.

This should be supported by IE8 and up, according to [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t1210) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536739%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```js
function newFont(newSizeA) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
    for(i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].setAttribute('style', 'font-size:' + newSizeA + 'px' + '!important');
    }

}

newFont(20);
```

```html
<div class="a">asdf</div>
```

Comment: does this work with IE8? i don't have it on my current computer to test

Comment: @RON2015 I believe support for `.setAttribute` was introduced to IE at version 8, so it should work. I don't have IE8 to test, and I'm not sure of a sandbox site that supports IE8 to test on via VM, either.

Comment: Nice answer. This is the correct solution; I have deleted mine as incorrect.

Comment: elems[i].setAttribute('style', 'font-size:' + newSize + ' !important');  does add the !important in but it still won't override the previous font-size that is set in the stylesheet for some reason

Comment: @RON2015 I can't seem to reproduce that: http://jsfiddle.net/2of7bs4n/ It's overriding the CSS in the JSFiddle there.

Comment: that is very frustrating... it works as soon as I cancel the font-size in fire-bug

Comment: @RON2015 Are you using !important in your CSS as well? I would recommend removing that if possible, then you shouldn't need to use `!important` in your JavaScript, either.

Comment: sorry i realized i need to target the first anchor of that class lol...