# Using javascript to change background image

Tags: javascript, css

The page in question:
http://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace

I want to change this image in the #header from

http://a.thumbs.redditmedia.com/Qe0ePtRsgau_YfN8wmTL67xCd8Y3y1YVcMDk8pdzai0.png

to this new image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vssLD.png

Is there a way to do it by pasting code in the console panel? (client side)

I tried:

```
var header = document.getElementById("header");
header.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vssLD.png)  no-repeat!important';
```

Comment: Why dont use Greasemonkey?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, and your code would work if the `background-image` didn't have `!important` style on it. You can't override `!important` when editing properties via `.style`. This post should help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462537/overriding-important-style

Comment: This is an interesting question, in fact, because the problem is related to other rules overriding this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code, which relies on jQuery (which Reddit allows):

```
$("#header").attr('style', 'background: url(http://i.imgur.com/htDLyzu.png) no-repeat !important');
```

Or in JavaScript (requiring no jQuery):

```
var header = document.getElementById("header");
header.setAttribute('style', 'background:url(http://i.imgur.com/htDLyzu.png) no-repeat !important');
```

Comment: .css() doesn't work? why?

Comment: I believe it's because that there is already code with `!important` in it, which means that the code we're trying to add isn't overwriting, even with `!important`. That means we need to add it inline (by giving it a `style` tag). @Rao

Answer (score -1):

I am using a script for a BG switcher on my website and this (scrapped down to the basic) works

```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

    var bgSrc1 = "http://urlpic1.jpg";
    var bgSrc2 = "http://urlpic2.jpg";
    var bgElem = document.getElementById('showcase-row');
    var num = getRandomArbitrary(0,1);

    function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
      return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    }
    if(num >= 0.5){
        bgElem.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + bgSrc1 + "')";
        bgElem.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -80px";
    }else{
        bgElem.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + bgSrc2 + "')";
    }
});
```

As you see the only difference are the " " and ' '

Comment: I dont want to critizize any of these downvotes but this works for me and works with what you need 
answer edited

Comment: Chances are you got downvoted because your answer doesn't address the question. Your code **does not** solve the OPs question; his issue has to do with overriding `!important` styles, which your answer does not address. Quotation marks are optional: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168855/is-quoting-the-value-of-url-really-necessary