# Add on to previous styles with element.style

Tags: javascript, css

I have an html element that has a set style.

```
element.style {
  "existing css;"
}
```

I want to add on to the style without overwriting the "existing css". (e.g my style is opacity and pointer-events)

```
element.style = "opacity: 0; pointer-events: none;"
```

Result I'm looking for:

```
element.style {
  existing css;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Current Output:

```
element.style {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

I know I can just add a class but want to know if theres a way to use javascripts **element.style = "css"**. I have also tried:

```
element.style += "opacity: 0; pointer-events: none;
```

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let me get this straight. For each of the CSS key/value pairs you're trying to apply to the element, you  want to apply them as inline styling, but only if the existing inline styling doesn't already have a set value to the current CSS property. Is that it? Or do you want to overwrite the new value regardless of what's already in the element's inline style?

Answer (score 1):

This code:

`element.style.setProperty("some_property", "some_value", "important");`

will append a the style "some_property" with a value of "some_value" and mark it as "important", i.e. `element {some_property: some_value !important;}`.

so for your specific case,

```
element.style.setProperty("opacity", "0");
element.style.setProperty("pointer-events", "none");
```

should get the job done.

However, I've also ran across some code where you can apparently do something as simple as, `element.style["some_property"] = "some_value";`, but I don't think you will have the option as marking it as `!important`. I haven't tried this out myself, yet!

This question is definitively a repeat - [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1577204/3155240).

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = document.getElementById("div1");
d.className += " otherclass";
```

Comment: Please consider explaining a what you did and why you did it. Just giving a code snippet isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("div1").className += "otherclass";
```

Comment: "I know I can just add a class but want to know if theres a way to use javascripts element.style = "css""