# Element is not displayed after I change the style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this HTML inside some frame:

```
<body class="Toolbar" onload="InitDocument()" leftmargin="10" topmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0" marginwidth="0">
    <div id="divRefresh2" name="divRefresh" class="cssRefresh" style="display:none;"> 
        <span>some text</span>
    </div> 
</body>
```

at some point I need to display div with id = divRefresh2.

When I need display the element above I fire this js function:

```
function OnMapLoading()
{
    var frmParent = parent.frames["tbFrame"];
    var objDivRefresh = frmParent.document.getElementById("divRefresh2");
    if(objDivRefresh != null)
    {
        objDivRefresh.style.display='block';
    }
}
```

As you can see the function, OnMapLoading get element by div and set display to block.

In debugger I put breake point after this row:

```
objDivRefresh.style.display='block';
```

and in the debugger I see that display property changes to block, but in browser I dont see any changes the element is not displyed.

Any idea how can I fix the problem?

Comment: try `!important` : `objDivRefresh.style.display='block !important'`

Comment: Are any of that element's parents hidden? Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: There is no `!important` when setting styles with javascript? If you can see the display property changing in the console, the posted code works, you're targeting the correct element, and the style is set, so something else is the problem

Comment: @adeneo Of course you  can set `!importnat` in Js code:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462537/overriding-important-style

Comment: That answer is actually telling you that you can't, it inserts a style tag instead to solve that exact issue

Comment: why are you using html attributes for setting styles?