# How to modify a group of element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider this html **button** tag:

```
<button type="submit" name="perks_request_status" class="btn-flat disabled btn-small perks_request_status" id="perks_request_status" style="">{{ $perk->status }}</button>
```

with this following **css** definition (from the css framework that i am using)

```
.btn-flat.disabled, .btn-flat.btn-flat[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
    color: #b3b3b3 !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

How can i change/override its style using Javascript? I tried to define style of my id tag `perks_request_status` using method below but no effect has been reflect.

```
function changeStatusColor(status, element){
    switch(status){
        case 'Approved':
        element.style.color = '#00796b !important';
        break;
        case 'Drafted':
        element.style.color = '#01579b !important';
        break;
        case 'Cancelled':
        element.style.color = '#b71c1c !important';
        break;
        case 'Disapproved':
        element.style.color = '#d50000 !important';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about just changing the class name?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1577204/4332533

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not working is due to the `important` in the css. To override that we need to use `cssText`.
Please use below code in "changeStatusColor" function then it will work.

```
element.style.cssText = 'color:red !important';
```