# Display a hidden element using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a div that is hidden by the css, (display: none), when I click a button I want it to display `(document.getElementById("invite").style.display = "block";`
but this code does apparently only work on elements that aren't hidden by the css (if I do `document.getElementById("invite").style.display = "none";`  to hide it and then call the "block" on it it gets visible again. But for some reason it doesn't work for elements hidden by css, anyone know why and how I can show elements hidden with React?

Edit:
Might be worth mentioning that the css attribute has !important after it.

Comment: `.style.display = "block";` *should* override the existing CSS style that hides the element, can you show a [MCVE] illustrating the problem?

Comment: Added an edit, not sure if it's the !important that's doing it, but I need it to override material ui's css

Comment: If the CSS has `!important`, that's a problem - its specificity is too high. Any way you can remove that `!important`?

Comment: Ugly workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462537/overriding-important-style

Comment: I need the !important since otherwise the css attributes won't work since Material UI has its own

Comment: @user14200927 - `!important` is a last resort that shouldn't be necessary 99% of the time. Try just making your selectors more specific.

Comment: Fixed it by using ".style.setProperty("display", "inline", "important")", thanks for the link CertainPerformance

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `display: none !important;` style that you provided in the style css.

Since you have add it as `!important` this will not be over witten by any scripts.

You could make use of [CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) to add the `!important` again this.

Working example.

```js
function toggle(event) {
  var popup = document.getElementById("toggleElement");
  if (popup.style.display === "none") {
    popup.style.setProperty('display', 'block', 'important');
  } else {
    popup.style.setProperty('display', 'none', 'important');
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
#toggleElement {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 50px;
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle(event)">toggle</button>
<div id="toggleElement">
  Toggle Element
</div>
```