# remove bottom border for specific screen size

Tags: javascript

As you can see outer border are lighter than inner border
in this form i tried to remove the bottom border for specific screen size but its not working
I want when screen size matches then bottom border will remove

```js
var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 992px)");
myFunction(x);
x.addListener(myFunction);

function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) {
    document.getElementById("b-brdr").style.borderBottom = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-lg py-3" id="ofc_use">
  <div class="row mx-auto">
    <div class="border border-dark col-lg-3 bg-warning d-flex flex-column justify-content-center" id="b-brdr">
      <h5>FOR OFFICE USE ONLY</h5>
      <p>(to be filled by financial institution)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="border border-dark col-lg-3 d-flex align-items-center" id="b-brdr">
          <h4>Application Type*</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="border border-dark col-lg-1" id="b-brdr"><input type="checkbox" name="application" class="check form-check-input" required> New</div>
        <div class="border border-dark col-lg-2" id="b-brdr"><input type="checkbox" id="update" name="application" class="check form-check-input" required> Update</div>
        <div class="border border-dark col-lg-4" id="b-brdr">
          <h5 class="d-inline">KYC Number</h5>
          <p class="d-inline"> (Mandotary for KYC Update Request)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="border border-dark col-lg-2" id="b-brdr"><input type="text" id="kyc" class="form-control border-0 h-100"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="border border-dark col-lg-3 d-flex align-items-center" id="b-brdr">
          <h4>Account Type*</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="border border-dark col-lg-2" id="b-brdr"><input type="checkbox" name="account" class="check form-check-input" required> Normal</div>
        <div class="border border-dark col-lg-2" id="b-brdr"><input type="checkbox" name="account" class="check form-check-input" required> Minor</div>
        <div class="border border-dark col-lg-5" id="b-brdr"><input type="checkbox" name="account" class="check form-check-input" required> Aadhaar OTP-based e-KYC(in non face to face mode)</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use css media queries. It is much simpler and doesnt require any js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```js
var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 992px)");
myFunction(x);
x.addListener(myFunction);

function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) {
    var div_list = document.querySelectorAll('#b-brdr');
    var div_array = [...div_list]
    div_array.forEach(div => {
      div.style.cssText  = "border-bottom:none !important;";
    });
  }
  else{
    var div_list = document.querySelectorAll('#b-brdr');
    var div_array = [...div_list]
    div_array.forEach(div => {
      div.style.cssText  = "";
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-lg py-3" id="ofc_use">
  <div class="row mx-auto">
    <div class="border border-dark col-lg-3 bg-warning d-flex flex-column justify-content-center" id="b-brdr">
      <h5>FOR OFFICE USE ONLY</h5>
      <p>(to be filled by financial institution)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="border border-dark col-lg-3 d-flex align-items-center" id="b-brdr">
          <h4>Application Type*</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="border border-dark col-lg-1" id="b-brdr"><input type="checkbox" name="application" class="check form-check-input" required> New</div>
        <div class="border border-dark col-lg-2" id="b-brdr"><input type="checkbox" id="update" name="application" class="check form-check-input" required> Update</div>
        <div class="border border-dark col-lg-4" id="b-brdr">
          <h5 class="d-inline">KYC Number</h5>
          <p class="d-inline"> (Mandotary for KYC Update Request)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="border border-dark col-lg-2" id="b-brdr"><input type="text" id="kyc" class="form-control border-0 h-100"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="border border-dark col-lg-3 d-flex align-items-center" id="b-brdr">
          <h4>Account Type*</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="border border-dark col-lg-2" id="b-brdr"><input type="checkbox" name="account" class="check form-check-input" required> Normal</div>
        <div class="border border-dark col-lg-2" id="b-brdr"><input type="checkbox" name="account" class="check form-check-input" required> Minor</div>
        <div class="border border-dark col-lg-5" id="b-brdr"><input type="checkbox" name="account" class="check form-check-input" required> Aadhaar OTP-based e-KYC(in non face to face mode)</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Changes made:myFunction changed to `document.getElementById("b-brdr").style.cssText  = "border-bottom:none !important;";`

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Novice_in_dotnet/6rp7c9L1/10/)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1577204/2820150)

Comment: it remove only 1st border but not all inner border

Comment: updated fiddle and snippet. does it help?

Comment: I've doubt, do you mean all four borders of b-brdr?

Comment: not all four but all bottom border who have id b-brdr

Comment: updated snippet and fiddle. please check. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@Md Mohtesham Azam add this to your css below:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px){
    #b-brdr { border-bottom:0 !important;}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).