# React, onMouseOver not working on child component but it does in button

Tags: reactjs, onmouseover

Given the following code: -[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-leaf-hikwsc?file=/src/App.js:0-752)-

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

const B = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <C>C inside B</C>
    </div>
  );
};

const C = ({ children, estado = "lightgrey" }) => {
  const handleBoxToggle = (e) =>
    (e.target.style.backgroundColor = "blue !important");

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        backgroundColor: estado,
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        minWidth: "1rem",
        minHeight: "1rem",
        outline: "1px solid black"
      }}
      onMouseOver={(e) => handleBoxToggle(e)}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onMouseOver={() => alert("hi")}>Alert on hover Button</button>
      <B></B>
      <C>Alert DIV estado</C>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Why does the button display the alert on mouse over but the component 'C' does not? Shouldn't it have the function integrated? How can I make the mouseover on 'C' Component work? (it will be created dinamically many times).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call your function `handleBoxToggle` inside `onMouseOver` event callback

Pass it like this `onMouseOver={handleBoxToggle}`

Comment: I did a simple example to post it here, but in my main App, it doesn't work, nothing happens. I'm calling  on component A the Component B which uses Component C as child.

Comment: Can you show how you passed your function to `onMouseOver` in main App? Did you understand what I meant in answer above?

Comment: Still not my main app (it is too much code for a simple example) but please refer to the code sandbox above to see updated doubt. Thank you!

Comment: @Germán check please [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-butterfly-2zzxp4?file=/src/App.js). I hope that's what you meant

Comment: Please Refer to my updated CodeSandBox on top to check the current doubt.

Comment: I [forked your sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-lake-u2xb84?file=/src/App.js) check please. You should pass your event named `e` to `handleBoxToggle` as its argument. `blue !important` doesn't work because you should remove `!important`

Comment: I deleted important and it works now. I don't actually get why, but it works. I'll close this question if you want to post your answer. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462537/overriding-important-style

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your funtion like

```
onMouseOver={handleBoxToggle}
```

OR if you want to pass any arguments to this funtion you can call like

```
onMouseOver={() => handleBoxToggle()}
```