Adding style property to individual class elements on click, IF their data is modified
I'm trying to make a browser dress up game with separate tabs for draggable items (so tops, bottoms, etc). This is the JavaScript code for how the tabs function.
function openTab(event, Category) {
  var i, tabcontent, btn;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="btn" and remove the class "active"
  btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
  for (i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].className = btn[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(Category).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

I also have a button that resets items to their original position when clicked.
$(".clothes").data({
    'originalLeft': $(".clothes").css('left'),
    'origionalTop': $(".clothes").css('top')
 });
 
$("#reset").click(function() {
   $(".clothes").css({
     'left': $(".clothes").data('originalLeft'),
     'top': $(".clothes").data('origionalTop')
   });
});

My problem is that, when switching between tabs, the items get hidden, even if they're moved onto the doll.
So my solution would be to add style.display = "block" !important to .clothes if their original position is modified and remove this style property when the #reset button is clicked.
But I'm having a difficult time understanding JavaScript, so I don't know how to actually write that or how to search for a similar scenario and use that code.
This is what I tried, but it just breaks. And I don't want it to affect all .clothes items, just those that were moved, or at least clicked.
$(".clothes").click(function() {
    .clothes img.style.display = "block" !important;
}

(To see the code in action, https://pixis.neocities.org/dressup/meliextra)

It seems like there should be an error message in your dev console. Regardless, you might look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462537/overriding-important-style

@mykaf I tried both element.style.setProperty and element.setAttribute, but it's not working. Am I writing it wrong? $(".clothes").click(function() { $(".clothes").style.setProperty("display", "block", "important"); } Regardless, this seems to be what I need, thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

It's hard to say without the full context. You haven't included your html or css. Is there an error in your dev console? Does it do something other than what's expected? "It's not working" isn't particularly helpful.

Also, this seems fishy: .clothes img.style.display. Seems like there should be an error related to this line.

@mykaf I'm not getting any errors. The result I have is that all the items with the .clothes class are now hidden and clicking on the tab buttons does nothing, so I thought I might have worded the function incorrectly. I'll try studying it so I'll understand how to use it correctly.
.clothes img.style.display did not alert me of any errors, either. The items in the .clothes class are all images, which is why I tried writing it like that. I have since removed it in favour of the line in my previous comment.
Tyvm for your help. At least now I know what I should be looking into.

.clothes img.style.display = "block" !important; isn't valid syntax, on multiple counts. It would still be very helpful to see the relelvant htm.l

@mykaf This is how the .clothes items are coded.
<div id="Tops" class="tabcontent">  <img id="top1" src="img.png" alt="top1" height=78px; width=158px; class="clothes"/>  </div> You can view the code in its entirety here: view-source:https://pixis.neocities.org/dressup/meliextra. Though I'd really rather not trouble you any further.
